# Spring Data JPA: Using multiple entity in SpEL notation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I used `SpEL` for generic entity name in my `Spring Data JPA` repositories. This time, I need to join 2 tables via `JPQL` and for this purpose, I am wondering if I can use multiple entity by passing to the repository and then using it in my query as `SpEL` 's `${#entityName}`. So, is it possible?

***DiningRepository:***

```
@Query("select d as dining, dg as diningGroup, s as site " +
        "from Dining d " +
        "         join DiningGroup dg on d.groupUuid = dg.uuid " +
        "         join Site s on dg.siteUuid = s.uuid " +
        "where d.uuid = :uuid")
Optional<GroupAndSiteProjection> findByUuid(@Param("uuid") UUID uuid);
```

Here is projection where I collect `Dining`, `DiningGroup` and ``Site` result:

```
public interface GroupAndSiteProjection {

    Dining getDining();

    DiningGroup getDiningGroup();

    Site getSite();
}
```

The method is in `DiningRepository` and `${#entityName}` gets `Dining` entity. But I want to use also `DiningGroup` by passing it to the repository as generic e.g. `DiningRepository<Dining, DiningGroup>`... Is it possible?

Comment: How would you access it if you did not use SPEL but accessed the data as POJO with getters?

Comment: I access using `GroupAndSiteProjection` preojection interface by getters.

Comment: @cyberbrain Chico? Any reply please?

Comment: can you give some details about `GroupAndSiteProjection` ? Your code example is really sparse, far away from a [mre].

Comment: @cyberbrain Sorry, I updated the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly: previously you used `${#entityName}` inside your `@Query` to get rid of the hard coded `Dining` entity name. But now you need a projection and want to replace both, `Dining` and `DiningGroup` with something dynamic in the query? What about `Site`??
(Sorry for my many questions, but maybe I'm not knowing that much as I though initially  so I have to do what I'm good in: asking "dumb" questions... ;-)

Comment: Yes, actually Site is fixed and it would be ok if I can pass Dining and DiningGroup in a generic, etc. way.

Comment: To my understanding this is not supported, but don't take this as a final answer (that's why it's only a comment...)

Comment: According to my searches, yes it seems to be like so. Thanks for your helps.